# Embedding vectors not being updated when using Tensorflow on window classification

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am trying to implement a window based classifier with tensorflow,

The word embedding matrix is called `word_vec` and is initialized randomly (I tried Xavier also).

And the `ind` variable is the a vector of the indices of the word vectors from the matrix.

The first layer is `config['window_size']` (5) word vectors concatenated.

```
word_vecs = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([len(words), config['embed_size']], -1.0, 1.0),dtype=tf.float32)
ind = tf.placeholder(tf.int32,  [None, config['window_size']])
x = tf.concat(1,tf.unpack(tf.nn.embedding_lookup(word_vecs, ind),axis=1))
W0 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([config['window_size']*config['embed_size'], config['hidden_layer']]))
b0 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([config['hidden_layer']]))
W1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([config['hidden_layer'], out_layer]))
b1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([out_layer]))
y0 = tf.nn.tanh(tf.matmul(x, W0) + b0)
y1 = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(y0, W1) + b1)
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, out_layer])
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(y1), reduction_indices=[1]))
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.5).minimize(cross_entropy)
```

And this is how I run the graph:

```
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)
for i in range(config['iterations'] ):
    r = random.randint(0,len(sentences)-1)
    inds=generate_windows([w for w,t in sentences[r]])
    #inds now contains an array of n rows on window_size columns
    ys=[one_hot(tags.index(t),len(tags)) for w,t in sentences[r]]
    #ys now contains an array of n rows on output_size columns
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={ind: inds, y_: ys})
```

**The dimensions work out, and the code runs**

However, the accuracy is near zero, and I suspect that the the word vectors aren't being updated properly.

How can I make tensorflow update the word vectors back from the concatenated window form ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your embeddings are initialised using `tf.Variable` which are by default trainable. They will be updated. The problem might be with the way you are calculating loss. Look at these following lines

```
y1 = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(y0, W1) + b1)
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, out_layer])
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(y1), reduction_indices=[1]))
```

Here you are calculating the softmax function which converts the scores into probabilities

[image: softmax equation]

If the denominator here becomes too large or too small then this function can go for a toss. To avoid this numerical instability usually a small `epsilon` is added like below. This makes sure that there is numerical stability.

[image: softmax_with_epsilon]

You can see that even after adding an `epsilon` the softmax functions value remains the same. If you don't handle this on your own then the gradients may not update properly due to vanishing or exploding gradients.

Avoid the three lines of code and use the tensorflow version 
`tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`

Note that this function will calculate the softmax function internally.
It is advisable to use this instead of calculating the loss manually. You can use this as follows

```
y1 = tf.matmul(y0, W1) + b1
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, out_layer])
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=y1, labels=y_))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize your `W` matrices to a random value.
Right now `y1` is always 0 due to zero initialization.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've now initialized the Ws and Bs with `tf.random_uniform` between 0 and 1, and the results did not improve, any idea why ?

Answer (score 1):

Your starting of algorithm is fine. But I have some confidence this approach don't work. Actually word to vector trick is became working after estimation approximations are found applicable for NLP . For example techniques called ***Importance Sampling*** and ***Noise-Contrastive Estimation***.

So why straight approach doesn't work? I think, that to solve the task model must precisely find right 1 answer from large vocabulary, say 80000 words. 1 from 80000 - is too hard to optimize model, gradients didn't tell anything for most cases.

**Update**:
I forgot to mention that main reason of estimation approximation is performance issues of straight approach were you have large output. Each iteration steps for all examples require calculating loss for each output unit (like 80000). Optimization will take long time to be intractable.

How to implement right word2vec using sampling and NCE loss? Easily, following tutorial [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/udacity/5_word2vec.ipynb), loss function looks like this:

```
loss = tf.reduce_mean(
    tf.nn.sampled_softmax_loss(weights=softmax_weights, biases=softmax_biases, inputs=embed,
                           labels=train_labels, num_sampled=num_sampled, num_classes=vocabulary_size))
```

Main idea is we need only few m negative samples and 1 positive. Where m is far less than actual vocabulary size.

Tensorflow also has [tf.nn.nce_loss](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/nn/candidate_sampling#nce_loss)

You can read more about mathematical behind of approaches in online book [www.deeplearningbook.org](http://www.deeplearningbook.org/) (I. Goodfellow et al)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am actually training a POS tagger (not word2vec) with a window based model, would the NCE loss be applicable here as well ?

Comment: Oh, that is clarified. I'm not sure, NCE and sampling are underestimation of full softmax. If you have relatively small number of tags, than using regular softmax is preferred. Your code seems to work now :) To debugging, mb helps monitoring gradients, activations using summary operations https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/summary. Are you feeding model "right" data? :)